# load feedburner RSS feed over HTTPS

Tags: rss, https, feedburner

we are trying to read an RSS feed into our web application using a jquery plugin. That works fine as long as we are on a HTTP connection.

The problem is that our application works in HTTPS and the feedburner URL doesn't support httpS. Feedburner seems to have an invalid certificate installed on that service.

Does anyone know how we can solve this problem best? Should we move away from feedburner?

Comment: Which plugin are you trying to use? How does it retrieve the feed? What error do you get? Can you give us an example feed that doesn't work for you?

Comment: You can try any feedburner feed. They don't support HTTPS. We are using the jgfeed plugin for jquery: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jgfeed

Comment: I'd also like to be able to access feedburner RSS over HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

The only option I can think of is to proxy the FeedBurner requests through your own server that does support SSL.  Basically, your web page does something like:

```
$.jGFeed('https://your-server.example.com/feedburner/xxx')
```

Then you could set up something like the following in Apache:

```
ProxyPass /feedburner/ http://feeds.feedburner.com/
```

That means the request to feedburner is over HTTP while the request from the browser is over SSL to your server.